Why png Base64 image not working on meta og:image?
I tried to set an open graph image by data:image/png;base64, but it not working. Why ?
Here's my approach:
<meta content="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO         9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" property="og:image">
Meta og image not supporting png base 64 image format

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?

why is what not working?
